# Can I make TortoiseGit remember by password? (using multiple BitBucket accounts)

Tags: git, version-control, passwords, bitbucket, tortoisegit

I am working on several Git repositories which are hosted at BitBucket (with different BitBucket accounts). Whenever I do a pull or push, TortoiseGit asks my password.

Is there a way to make TortoiseGit remember the password for the particular BitBucket account I am using for that particular repository?

Comment: Are you accessing through HTTP or SSH?

Comment: HTTPS, the repository URL is https :// bitbucket.org / etc..

Answer (score 2):

1. Activate wincred or any other credential storage (e.g., using TortoiseGit settings -> Git -> Credentials). This allows you to store username and passwords.
2. As you want to use different usernames you have to include the username into the pull/push URL (by using @ notation: `https://username@example.com/path`)